# Implement Dynamic pivot in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot, mysql-workbench, dynamic-pivot

I write an mysql query

```
SELECT id,GROUP_CONCAT(answer.text) as answer,question.question_name as question
FROM user_answers
inner join answer on user_answers.answer_id=answer.answer_id
inner join question on answer.question_id=question.question_id
GROUP BY id,question.question_id
```

I am getting a result as

[image: result]

But I  want the answer as

[image: required]

How can I pivot my data. ?

I tried this query . But not getting actual result. its duplicating

```
SELECT  id,
     GROUP_CONCAT(
         CASE 
             WHEN question.question_name = 'Household'
             THEN answer.text
             ELSE NULL 
         END
     ) AS Household,
     GROUP_CONCAT(
         CASE 
             WHEN question.question_name = 'Dependents' 
             THEN answer.text
             ELSE NULL 
         END
     ) AS Dependents,
     GROUP_CONCAT(
         CASE 
             WHEN question.question_name = 'Generation'
             THEN answer.text
            ELSE NULL 
         END
     ) AS Generation,
     GROUP_CONCAT(
         CASE 
             WHEN question.question_name = 'Gender' 
             THEN answer.text
             ELSE NULL 
         END
     ) AS 'Gender',
     GROUP_CONCAT(
         CASE 
             WHEN question.question_name = 'Race' 
             THEN answer.text
             ELSE NULL 
         END
     ) AS 'Race',
     GROUP_CONCAT(
         CASE 
             WHEN question.question_name = 'FinancialGoals' 
             THEN answer.text
             ELSE NULL 
         END
     ) AS 'FinancialGoals'
FROM user_answers
inner join answer on user_answers.answer_id=answer.answer_id
inner join question on answer.question_id=question.question_id
GROUP BY id,question.question_id,question.question_name
```

result is

[image: duplicate]

Added aggressive function and still result column is duplicating

Comment: hi @Luuk , I tried that , but I am getting duplicated value.. I updated the question with duplication

Comment: You have to re-read the link I posted earlier, and pay more attention. (There is an aggregate function missing in your SQL statement (actually more than one).)

Comment: added aggregate also.. but same output. its duplicating

Comment: @Luuk Thankyou. .. :)  I got my issue..
issue in group by clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer.

```
SELECT  id,
         GROUP_CONCAT(
             CASE 
                 WHEN question.question_name = 'Household'
                 THEN answer.text
                 ELSE NULL 
             END
         ) AS Household,
         GROUP_CONCAT(
             CASE 
                 WHEN question.question_name = 'Dependents' 
                 THEN answer.text
                 ELSE NULL 
             END
         ) AS Dependents,
         GROUP_CONCAT(
             CASE 
                 WHEN question.question_name = 'Generation'
                 THEN answer.text
                ELSE NULL 
             END
         ) AS Generation
       
    FROM user_answers
    inner join answer on user_answers.answer_id=answer.answer_id
    inner join question on answer.question_id=question.question_id
    GROUP BY id
```

Comment: You also can check out the [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/how-can-i-return-pivot-table-output-in-mysql) of this one containing dynamic approaches as the title has, where no need to repeat each cases of `question_name` column.